# How to implement your own Faker provider in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, faker, laravel-seeding

I want to create a custom provider for Faker in Laravel (e.g. one for a random building name).

Where do I store the custom provider in my application and how do I use it?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/adding-a-custom-faker-service-provider

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should use `php artisan` to generate the custom provider...

On the command line, navigate to the root of your app and type...

```
php artisan make:provider FakerServiceProvider
```

That should generate a new provider in the `app/Providers` folder.  Here is what my register function looks like going off the example in the faker docs.

```
/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('Faker', function($app) {
        $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
        $newClass = new class($faker) extends \Faker\Provider\Base {
            public function title($nbWords = 5)
            {
                $sentence = $this->generator->sentence($nbWords);
                return substr($sentence, 0, strlen($sentence) - 1);
            }
        };

        $faker->addProvider($newClass);
        return $faker;
    });
}
```

I'm using an anonymous class here.  If you have php < 7, you would likely need to create a new file with your new provider class and pass that in.  Make sure you also add this new provider to your `providers` array in `config/app.php`.

Now that it's registered, you can grab your new faker class using the following...

```
$faker = app('Faker');
echo $faker->title;
```

Additionally, if you go through the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/facades you should also be able to make a `Faker` facade quite easily.  All the heavy lifting is done, you'd just have to create the new facade class, have `getFacadeAccessor` return `'Faker'`, and add it to your `facades` array in `app/config.php`.

Then you can simply use it like so...

```
echo Faker::title;
```

Comment: I had `$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {...` in factories, so I changed binding name to `Faker\Generator`.

Comment: @x-yuri Could you be more precise about what you have done? I have a similar requirement for my project

Comment: @rap-2-h From what I can see, I probably meant, that the code in the answer binds to `Faker` class (`$this->app->singleton('Faker'...`). But since I had `Faker\Generator` in `database/factories`, I probably bound to `Faker\Generator` to make use of extra formatters (`title` in this case).

Comment: I kept the suggested binding to `Faker` and added a second binding to `Faker\Generator` below it, which redirects to `Faker`. I decided to keep both `singleton` declarations within the `FakerServiceProvider` class. Custom Faker providers are now working in factories, and the Faker singleton is still accessible via `app('Faker')`. Sorry for the minification, but here's the code: `$this->app->singleton('Faker\Generator', function($app) { return app('Faker'); });`

Comment: Great implementation! How do you get your IDE to predict and recognize these added methods? I am using Laravel IDE for PhpStorm and they aren't being picked up.

Comment: I would recommend wrapping the `$this->app->singleton()` call in `$this->app->runningUnitTests()` so this doesn't register unless you're actually running tests.

Answer (score 9):

Create your custom provider class and save it under app/Faker/CustomProvider.php. Code:

```
namespace App\Faker;

use Faker\Provider\Base;

class CustomProvider extends Base
{
    public function customName()
    {
        return $this->generator->sentence(rand(2, 6));
    }
}
```

Then you need just add your custom provider to faker by addProvider method. Example of laravel's factory  with adding custom provider:

```
<?php
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Models\Model::class, function(Faker $faker) {
    $faker->addProvider(new App\Faker\CustomProvider($faker));

    return [
         'name' => $faker->customName,
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I found this worked better, as it did not require my `$faker` instance to be instantiated with `resolve()`:

```
public function register ()
    {
        $this->app->bind( Generator::class, function ( $app ) {

            $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
            $faker->addProvider( new CustomFakerProvider( $faker ) );

            return $faker;
        } );

    }
```

Comment: this works for me i just changed  `$this->app->bind(` to   `$this->app->singleton(`

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest way to do this is to call a method in a `ServiceProvider` class that check if Faker is installed (it should not be in production), then extends the core definition.

```php
use Faker\Generator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
         // other stuff ...
         $this->registerFaker();
    }

    private function registerFaker()
    {
        if (class_exists(Generator::class)) {
            $this->app->extend(Generator::class, function (Generator $generator, $app) {
                $generator->addProvider(new MyCustomProvider($generator));
                
                return $generator;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using Laravel factories you can just the withFaker method like so

```
/**
 * Get a new Faker instance.
 *
 * @return \Faker\Generator
 */
protected function withFaker()
{
    $faker = parent::withFaker();
    $faker->addProvider(new CustomProvider($faker));
    return $faker;
}
```

This will add the provider to the Generator instance being used by the factory, therefore it will only be available in the factory you overloaded the method in.