# How to define external method in faker generator?

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I just want to import some fake data for my music table like Genres(rap, pop, rock etc..) is it possible to define my own method ? Because I haven't found anything relevant to music

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is to add a new provider.

https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/#how-to-create-a-provider

There's also already a thread on this:
[How to implement your own Faker provider in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250776/how-to-implement-your-own-faker-provider-in-laravel)